# What is the second number in a python weak reference's repr?

Tags: python, weak-references

I am running python 2.7 on Windows7.

In the following, why is the second number in the representation of the weak reference not the same as `id(f)`?

```
import weakref

class Foo(object):
    pass

f = Foo()
w = weakref.ref(f)
print("id(f): %s"%(id(f),))
print("w: %s"%(w,))

>>> 36036400
>>> w: <weakref at 022649F0; to 'Foo' at 0225DF30>
```

Since is says that the weak reference refers to Foo "`at 0225DF30`" I would have though that this number would be the address of `f`, which in CPython is supposed to be the same as the id.

Comment: `hex(36036400)` == `'0x225df30'`. what's the question again?

Comment: No need to be snarky :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to expect `id(f)` to display the same number as if you just print out `f`. This is not the case, as shown in this example:

```
>>> f
<__main__.Foo object at 0x10929df10>
>>> id(f)
4448706320
>>> w
<weakref at 0x10928cfc8; to 'Foo' at 0x10929df10>
>>> id(w)
4448636872
```

The other thing that didn't show up in your example is that in the output of `w`, the location of `'Foo'` is in hexadecimal.

```
>>> print 0x10929df10
4448706320
```

Using the numbers from what you gave us:

```
>>> print 0x0225DF30
36036400
```

So you can see that the numbers are actually the same; it's just that it's displaying in hex in one place and in decimal in the other.

Comment: `id(w)` has nothing to do with what the weakref `w` points to.

Comment: This answer would be clearer if in the part where you mention the hex versus decimal representations, you use the same numbers as in your example.

Comment: @DanielSank good point. I was using OPs numbers, so I made that clear and also added the numbers from my example.

Answer (score 3):

The integer 36036400 is the same as hexadecimal 0x225df30:

```
In [10]: hex(36036400)
Out[10]: '0x225df30'

In [11]: 36036400 == 0x225df30
Out[11]: True
```

You could use `%x` to see the hexadecimal representation of `id(f)`:

```
In [12]: print("id(f): %x"%(36036400,))
id(f): 225df30
```